# Что выполняет программа?

Tags: c

Я в Си только новичок. Программист, писавший программу, уехал. Помогите разобраться:

```
#include <tiny13.h>
#include <delay.h>
unsigned char svet = 1;
unsigned char onf = 0;
    // Pin change interrupt service routine
interrupt[PCINT0]
void pin_change_isr(void)
{
    if (PINB .4 != 0) {
    if (svet < 4)
        svet++;
    else
        svet = 1;
    onf = 0;
    }
    if (PINB .3 != 0) {
    onf = 1;
    // PORTB.1=1;PORTB.2=1; PORTB.0=1;
    }
    delay_ms(200);
}

void main(void)
{

#pragma optsize-
    CLKPR = 0x80;
    CLKPR = 0x00;
#ifdef _OPTIMIZE_SIZE_
#pragma optsize+
#endif
    // Input/Output Ports initialization
    // Port B initialization

    // Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=Out Func1=Out Func0=Out

    // State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=0 State1=0 State0=0 
    PORTB = 0x00;
    DDRB = 0x1F;
    // Timer/Counter 0 initialization
    // Clock source: System Clock
    // Clock value: Timer 0 Stopped
    // Mode: Normal top=FFh
    // OC0A output: Disconnected
    // OC0B output: Disconnected
    TCCR0A = 0x00;
    TCCR0B = 0x00;
    TCNT0 = 0x00;
    OCR0A = 0x00;
    OCR0B = 0x00;
    // External Interrupt(s) initialization
    // INT0: Off
    // Interrupt on any change on pins PCINT0-5: On
    GIMSK = 0x20;
    MCUCR = 0x00;
    PCMSK = 0x1F;
    GIFR = 0x20;
    // Timer/Counter 0 Interrupt(s) initialization
    TIMSK0 = 0x00;
    // Analog Comparator initialization
    // Analog Comparator: Off
    ACSR = 0x80;
    ADCSRB = 0x00;
    // Global enable interrupts
#asm("sei")
    //PORTB.0=1; //gr
    //PORTB.1=1; //re
    //PORTB.2=1; //ye
    while (1) {
    if (onf == 0) {
        switch (svet) {
        case 1:
        PORTB .0 = 1;
        PORTB .1 = 0;
        PORTB .2 = 0;
        break;
        case 2:
        PORTB .2 = 1;
        PORTB .0 = 0;
        PORTB .1 = 0;
        break;
        case 3:
        PORTB .1 = 1;
        PORTB .0 = 0;
        PORTB .2 = 0;
        break;
        case 4:
        PORTB .1 = 1;
        PORTB .2 = 1;
        PORTB .0 = 0;
        break;
        }
    }
    if (onf == 1) {
        if (svet < 4)
        svet++;
        else
        svet = 1;

        switch (svet) {
        case 1:
        PORTB .0 = 1;
        PORTB .1 = 0;
        PORTB .2 = 0;
        break;
        case 2:
        PORTB .2 = 1;
        PORTB .0 = 0;
        PORTB .1 = 0;
        break;
        case 3:
        PORTB .1 = 1;
        PORTB .0 = 0;
        PORTB .2 = 0;
        break;
        case 4:
        PORTB .1 = 1;
        PORTB .2 = 1;
        PORTB .0 = 0;
        break;
        }
        delay_ms(1000);
    }
    };
}
```

Comment: @bogdanbv, расскажите о проблеме, чуть подробнее, и отформатируйте код.

Comment: программатор вроде программируется. Светодиоды нибось мигают (unsigned char svet=1;)
delay_ms(1000); // это задержка исполнения команды в миллисекундах
Цикл крутится, значения проверяются, меняются. То что начинается на решетку это предпроцессорная директива, то что на // это комментарий для человека. Что еще осталось непонятым?

Comment: А в чём именно проблема?

Comment: Программа для устройства имитации работы светофора. Используется микроконтроллер ATtiny13. Мне просто нужно подробно разобраться в ней.